# WCF Security - Newbie questions -

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wshttpbinding

I've been reading about WCF security for a whole day and can't say I'm comfortable with it.

I've developed some WCF services and deployed them to a test server and can call from a client. Both sides C# / VS 2010. The services are hosted under IIS 6. No option to go more recent at the moment.

So  - I've read that I can only use HTTP with IIS 6 - which I believe restricts me to basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding as the binding.

I've also read that the XML sent over the wire using wsHttpBinding is encrypted, whereas basicHttpBinding is not.

So it looks like I want to go with wsHttpBinding as I will want some sort of authentication and I suppose user name / password will be passed along with the incoming messages.

First question is - if I use wsHttpBinding do clients have to call using https? And then do I need to worry about certificates etc. on the server?

Second question is - what security options are available to me? Do the callers have to be Windows users on the server, or can I make up my own user name / password and have that part of the service and the service do the validation and have nothing to do with Windows users? If I have to go with Windows users I suppose it's common to set up one user account on the server and have all callers use that?

The basic idea is I need to open this service to selected callers, but don't want just anyone to be able to discover the service and call it. I need to control somehow who calls the service. Is user name / password the standard way of doing this? Could I define a GUID for example which all callers would have to pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your first question. wsHttpBinding does not *require* HTTPS. You can use HTTP if you set the SecurityMode to Message or None. However, since you are proposing to send a username and password with the service calls you definately shouldn't do that. If you do then anyone will be able to look at the message in transit and read the username and password and your security is totally compromised. I'm afraid you will have to get a certificate and use HTTPS. It's not so bad though and there are lots of resources on the web to help you.

By the way, you can do HTTPS with basicHttpBinding aswell as wsHttpBinding. Also, you should consider using REST for simplicity. WCF has good support for it (webHttpBinding) and better support coming with the [Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP).

In answer to your second questions, you do not need the callers to be Windows users on your server and you can use a username and password. This is called Basic Authentication. Again, there is lots about it on the web. Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775.aspx).

If you do this you will obviously have to have a database to store usernames and password so you can validate then and grant or denay access to your service. The simplest way to achieve this with WCF is to use one of the default [membership providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx).

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for that quick reply. One thing I don't understand is you say I can use HTTP and set securityMode to message - isn't the message encrypted in that case? I'll look into this basic authentication. Another thing that's not clear - if I can secure basicHttpBinding the same way, why would I choose wsHttpBinding? Wouldn't basicHttpBinding give me a larger reach? I don't care what technology is calling me as long as I can authenticate the caller. Thanks again, Ray

Comment: With message security, the message body is encrypted. you still need a certificate for it and it can also give slower performance than HTTPS. It is mainly used in complex scenarios where messages are forwarded between several intermediaries before reaching the target service. wsHttpBinding and basic HttpBinding are both SOAP bindings. basic supports only basic SOAP but wsHttpBinding supports several WS-* protocols built on SOAP for e.g. reliable messageing etc. basic would generally give you better reach if you don't need these advanced features. REST would give you even wider reach though...

Comment: Cheers for that Mike. I have something going with basicHttpBinding and  securityMode=Transport. I did a self certificate using sslDiag. I think my next step is to set clientCredentialType = Basic - then I see how client must pass username. How do I intercept and validate this in the service if it's not a Windows user? Thanks Ray

Comment: Dominic Baier is a well known expert in everything to do with security in .Net and as usual he has an excellent post on this on his blog:  http://www.leastprivilege.com/HTTPBasicAuthenticationAgainstNonWindowsAccountsInIISASPNETPart3AddingWCFSupport.aspx